# CSS classes not working with svg elements

Tags: svg, vis.js

I'm using the vis.js library and most things work. Like when I manually style the elements with the "style" tag however when I use the class attribute the styles are not applied.

The SVG element

```
const svg = `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="420px" height="165px">
  <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background-color: #fff;height: 100%, width: 100%; display: flex; padding: 8px; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37); box-sizing: border-box;">
   // This doesn't work
   <div style="flex: 1;">
    <h1 class="testyh1">Report Id</h1>
    <h2 style="margin: 0; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: normal;">1</h2>
   </div>

   // This works
   <div style="flex: 1;">
    <h1 style="color: #0481E2; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 3px; font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;">Report Name</h1>
    <h2 style="margin: 0; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: normal;">Medicine-Stock</h2>
   </div>

  </div>
  </foreignObject>
  </svg>`;
```

CSS

```
.testyh1 {
  color: #0481E2;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use style tag and update these in HTML page with script tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
#mynetwork {
margin: auto;
width: 1000px;
height: 800px;
border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me nothing I do works so I just use the inline styles even though they repetitive.